# The union of two continuum sets is continual.

Tags: set-theory

How to prove that the union of two continuum sets is continual? Can I take two equinumerosity segments([0,1] and [1, 2] for example) instead of two continuum sets, union them and say that their union equals the continuum?

Comment: Your idea works. Assuming you've already shown $[0,1]$ has cardinality $\mathfrak c$, build a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1] \cup [1,2] = [0,2]$ (it should be clear what function to choose) and then appeal to the fact every set of cardinality $\mathfrak c$ is isomorphic.

Comment: But is such a solution complete? After all, this proof works only for sets whose elements are real numbers

Comment: You have to extend it to all sets using the definition of cardinality.

Comment: I should also note you need to show you can assume the sets are disjoint (else the cardinality would be smaller anyhow, and you need to start by showing it's *at least* continuum) and then you probably wanna work with $[0,1)$ to avoid technical issues with disjointness (else prove changing a single element in an infinite set doesn't change cardinality) and then carefully build up a bijection between your abstract sets using the real intervals, then apply your real interval argument, then push that argument forward under the bijections. A lot more is needed in the proof, but your idea is good.

Comment: Alternatively, $2\cdot\mathfrak c=2\cdot2^{|\Bbb N|}=2^{1+|\Bbb N|}=2^{|\Bbb N|}=\mathfrak c.$